# How can I achieve hot restart for flutter app from keyboard on vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I want a keyboard shortcut that will allow me to hot restart the app without restarting it with the debug bar or debug tab.

on vscode

Comment: Assuming you have the flutter plugin installed, go to keyboard shortcuts (⌘K ⌘S), then search "flutter: hot" - You'll see the hot reload and hot restart commands, and you can assign whatever binding you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the hot restart command:  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>F5</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to run Hot Restart:

1. Press **Ctrl+F5**
2. From the **Command Palette**, type: "***flutter: hot restart***".

Have a nice day...

Comment: Ctrl+F5 is a hot reload not a hot restart